# Python: Trying to speed up a program that is running very slow

Tags: python-2.7, io

So, this program parses an e-mail address and a plain-text password from a text file. Then, it runs them through a few encryption routines and appends the encrypted text onto the end of the e-amil address:password entry in a new file.

```
import io
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import struct

def str_to_a32(b):
  if len(b) % 4:
    b += '\0' * (4 - len(b) % 4)
  return struct.unpack('>%dI' % (len(b) / 4), b)


def a32_to_str(a):
  return struct.pack('>%dI' % len(a), *a)


def aes_cbc_encrypt(data, key):
  encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, '\0' * 16)
  return encryptor.encrypt(data)


def aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(data, key):
  return str_to_a32(aes_cbc_encrypt(a32_to_str(data), a32_to_str(key)))

def base64urlencode(data):
  data = base64.b64encode(data)
  for search, replace in (('+', '-'), ('/', '_'), ('=', '')):
    data = data.replace(search, replace)
  return data


def a32_to_base64(a):
  return base64urlencode(a32_to_str(a))


def stringhash(s, aeskey):
  s32 = str_to_a32(s)
  h32 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
  for i in xrange(len(s32)):
    h32[i % 4] ^= s32[i]
  for _ in xrange(0x4000):
    h32 = aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(h32, aeskey)
  return a32_to_base64((h32[0], h32[2]))


def prepare_key(a):
  pkey = [0x93C467E3, 0x7DB0C7A4, 0xD1BE3F81, 0x0152CB56]
  for _ in xrange(0x10000):
    for j in xrange(0, len(a), 4):
      key = [0, 0, 0, 0]
      for i in xrange(4):
        if i + j < len(a):
          key[i] = a[i + j]
      pkey = aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(pkey, key)
  return pkey


with io.open('user_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    with io.open('user_list_enc.txt', 'a') as enc_file:
        for line in file:
            email_split, pass_split = line.replace('\n', '').split(":")
            password_aes = prepare_key(str_to_a32(pass_split))
            uh = stringhash(email_split.lower(), password_aes)
            enc_file.write(email_split + ":" + pass_split + ":" + uh + "\n")
            print email_split + ":" + pass_split + ":" + uh + "\n"
```

Comment: Why does it call `aes_cbc_encrypt_a32()` so many times?

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning it. I borrowed most of this code from a project that utilizes the Mega.co.nz API. I am not sure why it calls that function so many times. Could that be what is making it so slow? Mega.co.nz encrypts the plain-text password that a user enters on their website in the manner shown in the code. I am simply trying to load a file that contains user:password sets of login credentials and then encrypt the password in the required way. I am then attempting to append that encrypted password to the end of the original credentials list in a separate file.

Comment: *Could that be what is making it so slow?* - yes. For an 8 character password, I think it gets called ~32,000 times, and I suspect that dominates everything else in the program. About the only things I can think of are inlining the functions to avoid the overhead of function calls, or using PyPy if Crypto.Cipher works with it, to see if the JIT can help. Maybe other people have better ideas.